# Calculating the determinant gives $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I need to calculate the following determinant in order to prove the following equality:

$$\det\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ -b & a & -d & c \\ -c & d & a & -b \\ -d & -c & b & a \end{pmatrix} = (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2.$$

I tried using Gauss-algorithm to get an easier matrix, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly.

Calling the $4$ lines $I$, $II$, $III$ and $IV$, I did:

(1) $II \cdot a$

(2) $III \cdot a$

(3) $IV \cdot a$

After this I did:

(4) $II' + I \cdot b$

(5) $III' + I \cdot c$

(6) $IV' + I \cdot d$

So finally I got the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ 0 & a^2+b^2 & bc-ad & ac+bd \\ 0 & ad+bc & a^2+c^2 & cd-ab \\ 0 & bd-ac & ab-cd & a^2+d^2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

I thought this would make the determinant a bit easier, unfortunately I must have done something wrong. Is multiplication with single lines allowed as I have done it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: When you multiply a row by $a$, you also multiply the determinant by $a$. You could try just expanding the determinant along the top row --- looks like there's a fair bit of cancellation.

Comment: Note that the matrix is orthogonal...

Comment: @Kaladin's method is very elegant. Is there are more elementary method though?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notice that the rows are perpendicular to each other and the length of the rows are all the same.If you call the matrix $M$ then 
$\det(M^tM)=\det(M^t)\det(M)=\det(M)^2$ But $$
M^tM=
(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{array}
\right)$$
Therefor $\det(M^tM)=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^4\Rightarrow \det(M)=\pm(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$

Set $N=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}}M$ then all the rows of $N$ have length $1$. Further $N$ is completely determined by its first row. Now we have $\det(N)=\pm 1$
. Notice that the determinant gives a smooth  function, $$\det:S^3\to \{-1,1\} $$ By sending $(a,b,c,d)$  to our matrix  and then to the determinant of this matrix. (This is smooth because it is a polynomial function). But the point $(1,0,0,0)\in S^3$ is mapped to $1$. Now we can conclude that because $S^3$ is connected, $\{-1,1\}$ is discrete, and our function is continuous, that the entire $S^3$ is mapped to $1$. Thus $\det(N)=1$ and also $\det(M)=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$

Comment: thank you very much, this looks great, however there're still things I don't understand yet. Why is $M^tM = (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ ? I thought for orthogonal matrices (haven't heard of them yet, so they'll appear soon in lesson I guess) $M^t M = I$ ?

Comment: I think you've got it a bit wrong because $\det(M^tM) = (\det M)^2 = x^2 \Longrightarrow \det (M) = \pm x$. So why is $\det(M)$ positive here?

Comment: I've have made an addition to show it has to be positive

Comment: Hello once again. What you've written above contains things that I don't have learned so far. Is there a different way, or can you explain me the things you wrote above (before editing your post!)?

Comment: It is probably a bit much to explain all. If this is indeed the beginning of the course they likely want you to do the brute calculation. Then mind the comment of Gerry Myerson

Comment: Okay, then I'll have to try my best ;-) I hope I will soon get an answer to why $M^t m = (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)...$ (see above). Thank you for your help and time that you spent :)