# Prove that $\left|\begin{smallmatrix}a&-b&-c&-d\\b&a&-d&c\\c&d&a&-b\\d&-c&b&a\end{smallmatrix}\right|=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb K$ where $\mathbb K$ is a field. Prove that
>
> $$\det \begin{bmatrix}
> a & -b & -c & -d\\ 
> b & a & -d & c\\ 
> c & d & a & -b\\ 
> d & -c & b & a
> \end{bmatrix} = (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$$

I'm looking for a smart way to solve this problem. If we denote

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & -b \\ 
b & a \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
-c & -d \\ 
-d & c \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

we have that
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
a & -b & -c & -d\\ 
b & a & -d & c\\ 
c & d & a & -b\\ 
d & -c & b & a
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ 
-B & A \\ 
\end{bmatrix} $$
So it's sufficient to proof that

$$ \det \begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ 
-B & A \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = (\det A - \det B)^2. $$

Help?

Comment: The last identity doesn't look good when $A$ and $B$ are $1\times1$ matrices.

Comment: hint: your matrix is the matrix representation of a quaternion

Comment: The correct identity for that last step is 
$$
\det \pmatrix{A&B\\-B&A} = \det(AA - B(-B)) = \det(A^2 - B^2)
$$
this works because the block matrices commute

Comment: Another approach is to simply observe that your matrix can be written as
$$
I \otimes A + \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0} \otimes B
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, and $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think you mean $\det(A^2+B^2)$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews of course; can't edit at this point, though.

Comment: If you must put a matrix in the title, use `smallmatrix`; please avoid things like `bmatrix` or `pmatrix` in titles.

Comment: Your matrix is the same as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706513/calculating-the-determinant-gives-a2b2c2d22 , except that the first row and the first column have been multiplied by $-1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calculate $$  P P^T $$  then think about it.

Or
$$  P^T P $$

Comment: You mean $P =  \begin{bmatrix}
a & -b & -c & -d\\ 
b & a & -d & c\\ 
c & d & a & -b\\ 
d & -c & b & a
\end{bmatrix} $ ?

Comment: @user242964 yes.

Answer (score 4):

Generally， if $B$ is symmetric such that $A^TB=BA$, then
$$ \det \begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ 
-B & A \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = \det (AA^T +BB^T). $$
In fact
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ 
-B & A \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ 
-B & A \\ 
\end{bmatrix}^T=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ 
-B & A \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
A^T & -B^T \\ 
B^T & A^T \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
AA^T+BB^T & -AB^T+BA^T \\ 
-BA^T+AB^T & AA^T+BB^T \\ 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
AA^T+BB^T & 0 \\ 
0 & AA^T+BB^T \\ 
\end{bmatrix} $$
and hence
$$ \det\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ 
-B & A \\ 
\end{bmatrix}=\sqrt{\det\begin{bmatrix}
AA^T+BB^T & 0 \\ 
0 & AA^T+BB^T \\ 
\end{bmatrix}}=\det(AA^T+BB^T).$$

Comment: How do you resolve $\pm$ on the square root?

Comment: @ZachTeitler, I think $\det\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ 
-B & A \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$ is positive but I do not know how to show so far.

Comment: the first identity should probably be $AB^T=BA^T$. Also, an argument to show the $\det$ is $+1$ is given in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/706532/173147