# A determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a $3\times3$ real matrix of the following form
$$
A=\left(
\begin{matrix}
a & b & c \\
* & * & * \\
* & * & *
\end{matrix}
\right),
$$
where $a,b,c$ are fixed. I would like to find the other entries of the matrix in such a way that $\det A = 0$ if and only if $a=b=c=0$ and no combination of $a,b,c$ appears at the denominator of the other entries.

So far I have tried with different combinations of $a,b,c$, but nothing seems to work. In particular, I always find a determinant that vanishes e.g. when $a=0$ but the others need not be zero, or something like that.

Is there a clever choice I do not see?

Comment: So none of $a,b,c$ can appear _anywhere_ in the $*$ entries?

Comment: They should appear only at the numerators of the other entries. E.g. the matrix with second row $a^2, b^2, c^2$ and third row $a^3, b^3, c^3$ would be ok, but the first condition on the determinant is not satisfied as $a=0$ is enough to have vanishing determinant.

Comment: Not appearing in a denominator is a semantic requirement and very difficult to enforce consistently. You could require that the solution must give a valid matrix for any $a,b,c$. That's more objective.

Comment: @Arthur yes that is a good point. Still, I am not sure whether the condition you suggest is easier to enforce. Denominators of the form $a^2+b^2+c^2$ or $|a|+|b|+|c|$ or $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^n$ would all work...

Comment: It's crazy how that is actually possible in dimension 4 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706513/calculating-the-determinant-gives-a2b2c2d22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to replace asterisks with continuous functions of $a,b,c$, so determinant is not zero when $a,b,c\neq0$.

Let $(a,b,c)$ be a point on a unit sphere. If determinant is non-zero, you can produce an orthonormal triple out of the rows (with Gram-Schmidt process). Take the second vector. It will be tangent to the sphere. So you have created a continuous vector field on a sphere.

But we know that a sphere [cannot be combed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

Comment: Thank you. I think this basically answers my question. I wonder now whether this can be done with non-continuous functions.

Comment: Perhaps one remark is that the Gram-Schmidt process gives you combinations of $a,b,c$ in the denominator of the other entries, but they all make sense under the assumption. Arthur pointed this out in the comments, so perhaps my problem should be phrased more precisely.

Comment: _whether this can be done with non-continuous functions._

Split the sphere into several pieces fitting half sphere (for example, octants). For each piece choose two non-collinear constant vectors in the non intersecting plane plane. For example octant $a,b,c\ge0$ doesn't intersect plane a+b+c=0, so we can choose two vectors $(1,0,-1)$ and $(1,-1,0)$. Repeat for every piece.

Answer (score 0):

*(Its not an answer but its too big for a comment).*

Let the following matrix $A$ has constant functions of $a,b$ and $c$ in the numerator
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
c & a & b \\
b^2 & c^2 & a^2
\end{bmatrix}=a^4+b^4+c^4+-abc^2-bca^2-acb^2
$$
If $a=0 \implies \det A = b^4+c^4 =0 \iff b=c=0$ (the same occours with $b,c$).

That shows us **if some $a,b$ or $c$ is zero, then the determinant will necessarily vanish only if all of them are also zero.** But that doesn't show us

$$\det A=0 \iff a=b=c=0$$

( we may have $a,b,c \neq 0$ such that $\det A = 0$ ).

Comment: Yes that is basically the same kind of things I have tried.