# How to derive the determinant of quaternion?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

It is true that

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
a & -b & -c & -d \\
b & a & -d & c \\
c & d & a & -b \\
d & -c & b & a 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

has a determinant $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$

However, I find it very difficult to derive it manually, I have tried to do row operations but it seems very complicated. Is there a more speedy way?

Comment: Your example does not satisfy $A^T=-A$ if $a\neq 0$.

Comment: Only in the case of $n\times n$-matrices with odd $n$ , we can derive that the determinant is $0$ without actually calculating it. No idea whether there is an "easy" way here.

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @Peter: When $n$ is even, the determinant of a skew-symmetric $n \times n$-matrix is always the square of the [Pfaffian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian).

Comment: I am sorry for not searching throughoutly, but it seems we have an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706513/calculating-the-determinant-gives-a2b2c2d22